# Excel: Combining columns with similar values into one

Tags: vba, excel

Another not so easy problem. Using VBA, I need to iterate over the column headers which have similar names (not exact) and combine the values in the first one of that kind separated by `;`.

Example data:

```
A (1) B (1) C (1) A (2) B (2) C (2) A(3) B (3) C (3) 
 15     25    35    45    100  200  300   600   700
```

Should dynamically be like this, deleting the extra columns (a lot of values are blank too which need to be accounted for:

```
A (1)            B (1)        C (1)  
15;45;300     25;100;600   35;200;700
```

EDIT: Changed data structure to be more accurate

I'm guessing first I need to loop and clean the data so they have the same name, because that's only thing to match on.

```
For i = 1 to lastCol Step 1
    columnVal = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
      If InStr(columnVal, "(") Then
         'Remove everything after first "("
      End If
       For j = 1 to lastCol
           For k = 1 to lastCol
              If ws.Cells(1, j).Value = ws.Cells(1, k).Value Then
                 'Create array with combined values
              End if
            Next k
        Next j
```

Not sure if this is the right approach so any help is appreciated

Comment: `InStr` returns the position of the search string. use that and `Left` to remove the right part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With Worksheets("CombineColumns") '<--| change "CombineColumns" to your actual worksheet name
        With .Range("B2").CurrentRegion '<--| change "B2" to your actual topleftmost cell
            SortRange .Cells '<-- sort columns by their header
            .Rows(1).Replace what:="(*)", replacement:="(1)", lookat:=xlPart '<-- make all "similar" header the same
            Aggregate .Cells '<-- aggregate values under each different unique header
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub Aggregate(rng As Range)
    Dim header As String, resStrng As String
    Dim iLastCol As Long, iCol As Long

    With rng
        header = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        iCol = 2
        iLastCol = 1
        resStrng = .Cells(2, 1)
        Do
            If .Cells(1, iCol) = header Then
                resStrng = resStrng & ";" & .Cells(2, iCol)
            Else
                .Cells(2, iLastCol).Value = resStrng
                .Cells(1, iLastCol + 1).Resize(2, iCol - iLastCol - 1).ClearContents
                iLastCol = iCol
                resStrng = .Cells(2, iCol)
                header = .Cells(1, iCol).Value
            End If
            iCol = iCol + 1

        Loop While iCol <= .Columns.Count
        .Cells(2, iLastCol).Value = resStrng
        .Cells(1, iLastCol + 1).Resize(2, iCol - iLastCol - 1).ClearContents
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub

Sub SortRange(rng As Range)
    With rng.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng.Rows(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange rng
        .header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I unfortunately cannot sort the columns due to other reasons and cannot use range due to performance issues (1000 columns)

Comment: are columns already properly sorted? what's your data actual range?

Comment: They aren't sorted as in the ones with the similar names are not directly next to each other, but I need to keep the order they are in. Range is approximately A1:ZZ2000 (but range is dynamic of course)

Comment: what did you mean by _"This also didn't work for me"_?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. It only combined the values for A, then there were blank columns and B was not combined

Comment: it worked for me with data as per your example, even mixed-up (hence the Sort). you may want to post your data with which my solution "didn't work"

Comment: I just updated how the data actually looks, sorry about that, but I need to keep the columns in that exact order, just combined

Comment: just to be on the same page: with your updated data my code works. please check it (allow Sort momentarily) before any further attempt getting rid of the Sort thing

Comment: Ok, my mistake, forgot to copy the sorting sub at the bottom. works with sorting

Comment: so you see that columns are kept in the exact order. just need to remove blank columns

Comment: Awesome, can just loop over after and delete columns if "". how can I make this dynamic so it doesn't only look for "(*)" but also " / *" and "#*"?

Comment: add as many `.Rows(1).Replace...` as you need specifying proper `what` and `replacement` parameters. Finally since my answer fulfilled your _original_ question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you